# mysqldump generates zero-length file

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with myqldump that generates a zero-length file. I tried it many times, but it seems that that it only outputs a zero-length file. I don't know why. Do I need to install something or what ?

```
  <?
    shell_exec("mysqldump -hlocalhost  -uroot -p  -A> db/ilamdb.sql ");
    echo "complete";
  ?>
```

Comment: What is the variable `$_db_database`? Is your variable `$_db`, or is it `$_db_database`?

Comment: You ought to capture the output as `$out = shell_exec()` and inspect it.

Comment: its just a variable and i calling my database

Comment: i try that but it has nothing to display

Comment: But my point is -what is the variable name?? It can be mis-interpreted by PHP since it is embedded in a string not surrounded by whitespace. Is it `$_db` or is it `$_db_database`?  You should surround the variable in `{}`

Comment: there, i changed it for you to understand my code. do i need to install something so that it can generate correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. Provide a full path to mysqldump
2. Provide a password for a user (root in your case). **Leaving `-p` means ask user for password interactively.**  Escape or put the password in quotes if it contains one of the following characters `* ? [ < > & ; ! | $`
3. For the good measure use `--no-defaults` option. You might not need this in your case.
4. And finally redirect stderr to stdout adding `2>&1` at the end of the command. That way you'll get the error message for debugging purposes in your file instead of just empty file if an error occurs.

Therefore your code to invoke `mysqldump` might look like this

```php
$pwd = '*******';
$cmd = "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -p'$pwd' -A> db/ilamdb.sql 2>&1";
shell_exec($cmd);
```